firebase/init.json 404 - While using signInWithPopup for Google Login
firebase/init.json shows 404 - While using signInWithPopup for Google Login . I am using authdomain with firebaseapp.com itself.
"use client";
import { Container, Button, Typography, Box, CircularProgress } from '@mui/material';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, getRedirectResult, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential, signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect } from "firebase/auth";
import axios from "./utils/axiosInstance";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Login() {
    const [inprogress, setInProgress] = useState(false);
    const [loginResponse, setLoginResponse] = useState<any | null>(null);

    const router = useRouter()

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "xxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxx.firebasestorage.app",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
        appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        measurementId: "xxxxxx"
      };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);

    getRedirectResult(auth).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })

    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            setInProgress(true)
            const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
        } catch (error) {
        }
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xs">
            ...
        </Container>
    );
}


The title of your question says signInWithPopup, but your code only shows signInWithRedirect.  Could you edit the question so that they question is specifically about the code you're showing?

You might also want to say more about what you're observing and how to reproduce it.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "firebase/init.json shows 404".

I resolved this issue by migrating to oAuth2
